# problems with synchronization parameter in SSIS

Tags: t-sql, ssis

I am using SSIS synchronization parameter while running SSIS package with stored procedure

```
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] 
    @execution_id,  -- execution_id from catalog.create_execution
    @object_type=50, 
    @parameter_name=N'SYNCHRONIZED', 
    @parameter_value= 1; -- turn on synchronized execution
```

is there any problem associated with synchronization parameter. I have not faced any till now. But want to know the possible issues.

Comment: https://andyleonard.blog/2015/11/the-synchronized-ssis-execution-parameter/

Comment: I want to know disadvantages of Synchronization parameter not how to do it